# Base58 Random String generator

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi i am searching all over the net, but cant find a RNG that use only Base58 Characters

123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz

Why i look for it, i have a PK where last 4 characters are missing.

Best in python 2

Cool if somebody can help me, i try this but get errors

```
import random, string
x = ''.join(random.choices('123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz', k=4))
print(x)
```

i am no tech guy so thankfull for all help
my target is to become a txt file with all the possible combinations at the end, if this is possible at all.

Comment: That code runs without errors.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: Ok if i try to run it, i have python 2.7 on the Win 10 pc
i get this back

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "T:\random.py", line 1, in <module>
    import random, string
  File "T:\random.py", line 2, in <module>
    x = ''.join(random.choices('123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz', k=4))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'choices'

Comment: Maybe add the `python-2.7` tag, since you wrote "Best", but apparently mean "Only".

Comment: I try this also on the Laptop with python 3.9 

this is the error on 3.9    AttributeError: partially initialized module 'random' has no attribute 'choices' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: And btw its cool to see how some rate a post ( question ) down, i write i am no tech guy and search for help, first time in this sort of forum. Result is that ppl expect from me that i know all the rules that have to be done for posting and tech information ! Curious and funny ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python 2.7 you can use `random.choice` (singular) and have it executed on a range:

```
x = ''.join(random.choice('123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz')
             for _ in range(4))
```

Comment: THX for this info, but i get allways this ... AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'choices'... error and now it create a random.pyc file also !? Is there another way or short script to do this sort of list txt file ??

Comment: Not `choices`, but `choice`. You quote a message that says `choices`. Don't use `choices`.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\NR1\Desktop\Base58 RNG test\random.py", line 1, in <module>
    import random, string
  File "C:\Users\NR1\Desktop\Base58 RNG test\random.py", line 3, in <module>
    for _ in range(4))
  File "C:\Users\NR1\Desktop\Base58 RNG test\random.py", line 3, in <genexpr>
    for _ in range(4))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'choice'

Comment: How can i answer here in a normal window, not this small thing hahahha

Comment: Did you by any chance call a script `random.py`? It looks like you are not importing the *real* `random` library...